# Perform function after navigating back to a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, viewcontroller, viewdidappear

I have a view controller that loads calendar data with the function 'readEvents()'. When I add events to my iOS calendar however the changes are not reflected in the app unless I restart the app and the view is loaded again. I would like to know how to tell the app to run the function again every time the user navigates to the view controller. I have tried this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    readEvents()
}

func readEvents(){
    //function for reading calendar
}
```

I thought that this would allow me to run the function every time the user navigates to the page, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You want to do this with delegates. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of time this morning to explain how to do it, but if you look for a delegates tutorial it should point you in the right direction

Comment: try calling in 'viewWillAppear'..

Comment: As soon as you want to update your list on addition of an calendar event, fire a delegate from that class & pass data which you would like to update, then through your delegate method receive the data & update your view accordingly. You can refer how delegates work from here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm (Simple Example)